# SQL Audit of Data That Has Been "Modified" Directly

Tags: sql-server, admin

Is there a way or a tool, that will provide an audit report of data that has been updated directly in SQL Server 2012?

We have applications that obviously add and update data, and these use special logins.

What concerns me, are database administrators who could potentially change a record directly without going through the application. Sometimes it is necessary, so I cannot remove their rights but I would like to obtain a report.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

> You can use sql server audit feature for this task. Using audit and
>   audit specification, you can check what query has been run by which
>   user at what time as well as on which object. Its so convenient to
>   find what actually has been added or modified on any objects. You sure
>   can use CTC but the creation of audit is much more easy that that of
>   defining CTC or CDC. Check out this site for audit details.:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx